# Combinations of no repeated elements in Python

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Itertool.combination code gives me all combination for a target value 
I have an array

```
a=[1,1,2,-2,-4] target =0
```

output I get from:

```
Itertools.combination is: [(2, -2), (1, 1, -2), (1, 1, 2, -4)].
```

But the concern is:- Once the number is used, it should not get repeated.
Required Output:- [(2,-2)] #As 2,-2 pair nets to 0. Code should not use 2 again to sum:1,1,2 and net that off with -4. [I dont want numbers to get repeated once it is used in one of the pair.]

```
# Reference code:-

    import itertools
    import numpy as np

    def subset_sum(target, numbers):

        array_num=np.array(numbers)
        for size in xrange(1, len(array_num) + 1):
             for c in itertools.combinations(array_num, size):
                 if sum(c) == target:
                   temp_var.append(c)
                   print "Length of array is ",len(array_num)

        return temp_var

    numbers=[1,1,2,-2,-4]
    target=0
    output=subset_sum(numbers)
    print output
```

Comment: Check if the current number is in `temp_var` and if it is then skip?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: this is unclear because the output could be many possibilities depended on which numbers are prioritary to be excluded and where to start

Comment: There might be chance where we get repeated numbers. Eg:-

a=[1,1,2,2,-2,-4]

Comment: Is there a way to get the index number for all the matched numbers? Than I will check for repetition and delete the duplicates

Comment: Why are you using numpy?

Comment: I am using Numpy because:- I want to create an array and save numbers inside the array so that I can manipulate the array later.

Comment: Do you have the additional requirement of trying to maximize the number of combos you get?  If so, that makes this problem significantly harder.

Comment: The only requirement is: once a number is used in a particular combination, that number should not be used again. [I want to save the combination of numbers into an array and delete those numbers from actual numbers array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
concat = lambda i,j: list(i if type(i) is list else [i])+list(j if type(j) is list else [j])
reduce(lambda x,y: x if any([u in j for j in (x if type(x) is list else [x]) for u in y]) else concat(x,y), reduce(lambda x,y: concat(x,y), [[[],filter( lambda x:sum(x)==target,list(itertools.combinations(a,u)))] for u in range(2,len(a)+1)]))
```

**Outputs:**

```
>>> concat = lambda i,j: list(i if type(i) is list else [i])+list(j if type(j) i
s list else [j])
>>> a=[1,1,2,-2,-4]
>>> target=0
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x if any([u in j for j in (x if type(x) is list else [x])
for u in y]) else concat(x,y), reduce(lambda x,y: concat(x,y), [filter( lambda
x:sum(x)==target,list(itertools.combinations(a,u))) for u in range(2,len(a))]))
(2, -2)
>>> a=[5,1,3,-4,-5]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x if any([u in j for j in (x if type(x) is list else [x])
for u in y]) else concat(x,y), reduce(lambda x,y: concat(x,y), [filter( lambda
x:sum(x)==target,list(itertools.combinations(a,u))) for u in range(2,len(a))]))
[(5, -5), (1, 3, -4)]
>>> a=[1,-1,2,-2,-4]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x if any([u in j for j in (x if type(x) is list else [x])
 for u in y]) else concat(x,y), reduce(lambda x,y: concat(x,y), [filter( lambda
x:sum(x)==target,list(itertools.combinations(a,u))) for u in range(2,len(a))]))
[(1, -1), (2, -2)]
>>>
```

> **EDIT:** This is because the op changed his intention by virtue of his later [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309493/python-itertools-combinations/46322819?noredirect=1#comment79609773_46322819)

```
f=lambda x:tuple(map(lambda x:a[x],x)) if type(x)==tuple else map(lambda x:f(x),x)
f(reduce(lambda x,y: x if any([u in j for j in (x if type(x) is list else [x]) for u in y]) else concat(x,y), reduce(lambda x,y: concat(x,y), [filter(lambda x:sum(f(x))==target,list(itertools.combinations(range(0,len(a)),u))) for u in range(0,len(a)+1)])))
```

This doesn't exclude already-used values of different indices:

```
>>> a=[21197595.75,11885337.56,-11885337.56,-11885337.56,-9312258.19]
>>> f(reduce(lambda x,y: x if any([u in j for j in (x if type(x) is list else [x
]) for u in y]) else concat(x,y), reduce(lambda x,y: concat(x,y), concat([filter
(lambda x:sum(f(x))==target,list(itertools.combinations(range(0,len(a)),u))) for
 u in range(2,len(a)+1)],[]))))
[(11885337.56, -11885337.56), (21197595.75, -11885337.56, -9312258.19)]
>>>
```